# PGRST202 Error when calling RPC with passed in parameter

Tags: postgresql, schema, rpc, supabase

I'm getting a 400 Bad request error when calling an RPC that has a string passed to it. The aim of the function is to return the row(s) where the `searchquery` matches the `suburb_name` in Supabase.

- Using NextJS 13 App Router and Supabase for backend with Docker.
- I have tried recreating the function but that does not seem to work and have tested connection to Supabase using a general function to return the first ten rows of my table which successfully rendered. Based on the error, it appears I may need to reset the schema cache as it's trying to search for the function "get_suburb_data" without a parameter in the schema cache.
- I have also validated the string passed being passed is valid.

**ERROR:**

> {"code":"PGRST202","details":"Searched for the function public.get_suburb_data without parameters, but no matches were found in the schema cache.","hint":null,"message":"Could not find the function public.get_suburb_data without parameters in the schema cache"}

**page.tsx:**

```
`"use client";
import { GetSummarySuburbData } from "@/app/database.types";
import { supaClient } from "@/app/supa-client";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

// Get Suburb Name from URL
function getSuburbNameFromURL() {
    const url = new URL(window.location.href);
    const pathname = url.pathname;
    const stringInURL = pathname.replace("/suburb/", "");
    const suburbInURL = stringInURL.replace(/&/g, " ");
    return suburbInURL;
}

export default function GetSummaryData() {
    const [suburbName, setSuburbName] = useState("");
    const [summaryData, setSummaryData] = useState<GetSummarySuburbData[]>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const searchQuery = getSuburbNameFromURL();
        console.log(searchQuery);
        setSuburbName(String(searchQuery));
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (suburbName) {
            supaClient.rpc("get_suburb_data", { searchquery: suburbName }).then(({ data }) => {
                setSummaryData(data as GetSummarySuburbData[]);
            });
        }
    }, [suburbName]);

    return (
        <>
            Test
            <div>
                {summaryData?.map((data) => (
                    <p key={data.id}>{data.suburb_name}</p>
                ))}
            </div>
        </>
    );
}`
```

**PostgreSQL:**

```
-- Return row where suburb_name matches searchQuery
CREATE FUNCTION get_suburb_data("searchquery" text)
RETURNS table (
id uuid,
suburb_name text,
state_name text,
post_code numeric,
people INT,
male REAL,
female REAL,
median_age INT,
families INT,
average_number_of_children_per_family text,
for_families_with_children REAL,
for_all_households REAL,
all_private_dwellings INT,
average_number_of_people_per_household REAL,
median_weekly_household_income INT,
median_monthly_mortgage_repayments INT,
median_weekly_rent_b INT,
average_number_of_motor_vehicles_per_dwelling REAL
)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
begin
return query
select id, suburb_name, state_name, post_code, people, male, female, median_age, families,
average_number_of_children_per_family, for_families_with_children, for_all_households,
all_private_dwellings, average_number_of_people_per_household, median_weekly_household_income,
median_monthly_mortgage_repayments, median_weekly_rent_b, average_number_of_motor_vehicles_per_dwelling
from summary_data
WHERE suburb_name ILIKE '%' || searchquery || '%'
AND summary_data.path \~ "root";
end;$$;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Supabase, the schema cache in Postgres is automatically updated. If you'd like to do it manually just to be sure you can run

```sql
NOTIFY pgrst, 'reload schema'
```

in SQL to make PostgREST reload it.

For your code sample

```
supaClient.rpc("get_suburb_data", { searchquery: suburbName })
```

It looks like you're only passing a `suburbName`, which is not compatible with the SQL function that takes 18 arguments. You'll either need to pass values for all arguments or update the function to provide a default value (the default can be null).